# DSolve general solution constants setting

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

The Mathematica Documentation reference for DSolve (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html), subsection Scope/Hyperbolic Partial Differential Equations,  contains an example:

```
weqn = D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, y}];
ic = {u[x, y, 0] == (1/10) (x - x^2) (2 y - y^2), 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, 0] == 0};
bc = {u[x, 0, t] == 0,
    u[0, y, t] == 0, u[1, y, t] == 0, u[x, 2, t] == 0};
(sol = FullSimplify[u[x,y,t]/.DSolve[{weqn,ic,bc},u,{x,y,t}][[1]],
 K[1]\[Element]Integers && K[2]\[Element]Integers])//TraditionalForm
```

The solution is a double sum given as

[image: solution]

The question is compound:

1. how come parameters are predetermined, before it is even known that the solution will contain K[ ] and not c1, c2, … labeled parameters?
2. the Input line defines K[1] and K[2], while the solution contains K[1] and K[3] - why? - looks like a discrepancy.

I would be grateful for any clarifications on the above and also, for some help with finding a way to extract an arbitrary term of the sum or obtain a partial sum, which does not replace only the upper limit, (e.g. infinity), as in all examples with sums as solutions in the Mathematica reference.

Comment: With v13.1.0, the result remains a `Piecewise` solution unless the assumptions are extended to `K[1] \[Element] Integers && K[3] \[Element] Integers && K[1] >= 1 && K[3] >= 1`. `K` is used rather than `C` because they are variables (indices in summations) rather than constants. `K` is used for variables or arbitrary functions. `C` is used for arbitrary constants.

Comment: Is the look of `sol /. {K[1] -> m, K[3] -> n}` better to your liking?

Comment: the `&& K[2]\[Element]Integers]` is mistake. I remember now seeing this before. May be even asked about it here but can't be sure. There is no `K[2]` in the solution. So this does nothing. There is only `K[1]` and `K[3]`

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the intended distinction between constants labels. Changing constant names did not help with the last part of my question. 

In ref/DSolve - Scope/General Partial Differentia Equations - an example solution  is given as an infinite sum. A finite part is activated by replacing the upper limit, ‘infinity’, of the sum, as follows:

`u[k_Integer] = \[Psi] /. Activate[First[sol] /. \[Infinity] -> k]`

This would extract the partial sum with the first k terms. What would be the mechanism for extracting any term or partial sum starting from an arbitrary term?

Comment: **What would be the mechanism for extracting any term or partial sum starting from an arbitrary term?** for partial sum I usually just replace $\infty$ with a numerical value  say 50 or 100 or whatever the number of terms you want (using standard /. command). Then Activate the sum. You do need to do this anyway to evaluate the sum and plot the solution.

Comment: If `sol = FullSimplify[u[x, y, t] /. DSolve[{weqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, y, t}][[1]], K[1] \[Element] PositiveIntegers && K[3] \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` (in V13), then the general term of the sum is, `First[sol]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1.** The `K[1]` and `K[3]` are summation variables. This means that they are dummy variables, and any other name could be used instead. They could also be named `c1` and `c2`. For a general discussion, see the Wikipedia entry on [free and bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).

**Question 2.** Since summation variables are dummy variables, it is quite possible that different versions of Mathematica produce solutions with different summation variables. I looked at the Mathematica documentation for `DSolve` for versions v12 and v13:

- https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12/ref/DSolve.html
- https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/DSolve.html

It seems that v12 used `K[1]`, `K[2]` and that v13 used `K[1]`, `K[3]`. OP seems to have code from the documentation v12 (or similar) but the output for v13 (or similar) which explains the discrepancy.

**Extracting finitely many terms.** One can use something like

```
sol/.{{K[1],1,DirectedInfinity[1]}->{K[1],1,5},
      {K[3],1,DirectedInfinity[1]}->{K[3],1,10}}//Activate
```

Comment: Btw, I think this is a rather ugly example in the documentation. The post-processing using `FullSimplify` should not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the precise and helpful answer! Especially, the last part, which worked for my problem beautifully. I did search the documentation for guidance, but could not find and would non have been able to work it out exactly on my own. Gratefully,

Comment: You are welcome.